# Preparing a water heater for storage

Tags: water-heater

I am in the process of gutting two houses. One has an electric water heater, and the other has a propane one. As I am taking the systems offline, how can I best prepare the units for storage? I think I should flush them to avoid sediment compaction. What about bacteria or other growth? Are there other considerations?

Comment: Disconnect electric or gas (preferable) or turn off with a large note not to turn on (or an actual lockout would be preferable to a note) and drain completely. "Bacteria or other growth" is less likely if they are dry, and you can kill any that does happen when you refill in any case.

Comment: @Ecnerwal sounds like an answer to me